# deal with confirm box in selenium, python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, alert

I want to click on a button in confirm box, in selenium browser, with python.

this picture is the confirm box. It contains more words than 'OK' or 'No'

[image]
[selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: no such alert] is what i get. when I try to try below
= driver.page_source
= alert.accept()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

In case you need to wait for the alert appearance and sometimes it will appear and sometimes no, this can be used:

```py
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.alert_is_present())
    alert = driver.switch_to.alert
    alert.accept()
    print("alert accepted")
except TimeoutException:
    print("no alert appeared")
```

Comment: already tried. keeps saying 'no such alert'